# What should I do if I get an error that template is not specified for this component in angular 4?

Tags: angular

Actually I change My component in angular and now it showing an error that I am not specified any template for this component.
My Controller name is Login.component.ts
and Code is

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-Login',
   // templateUrl:"Login.components.html"
    template:"hello"

})
export class LoginComponent  {


}
```

Comment: you need to change the class name in app.module

Comment: What does the error specifically say? The path to your template may be wrong. It may be `./login.component.html`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback ,its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these steps with me :
1. Add the new component name in the app.module.ts

```
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
```

2. Make sure there isn't a typo in the template url here. I think it should be somewhat like:

   `templateUrl:"./login.components.html",`

Change the urls according to you directory structure.